# DataBinding to classes

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, binding, data-binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>
> [Binding GridView to Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591081/binding-gridview-to-objects)

My C# app contains a Data Object like this:

```
public class Data
 {
    public class a {get;set;}
    public class b {get;set;}
 }

public class a
{
  public int first {get;set;}
}
public class b
{
  public int second{get;set;}
 }
```

I initialize my data when the application starts and my data changes evey time the app is running.

I have a dataGridView and I want to bind to the `first` property and to `second` property.  The DataGrid contains two columns, that bound to `first` and to `second` property.

How can I do this binding?  I don't want to change my dataSource nor do I want to add data.

*NOTE:* Remember that my data can change every time the app running.

Comment: possible duplicate of [binding gridview to objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591081/binding-gridview-to-objects)

Comment: You already asked the exact same question 2 days ago. Asking it again won't get you more answers

Comment: If you are using WPF toolkit's dataGrid, you have to reset your datacontext or itemsource every time you update the source.

Comment: @jsmith, the OP's using a DataGridView (Windows Forms)

Comment: @Thomas wow. Not even a possible duplicate...an *exact duplicate*.  I didn't want to lose my editing, so I copied that to the original question and will vote to close this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [binding gridview to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591081/binding-gridview-to-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Use INotifyPropertyChanged Interface and implement NotifyPropertyChanged() method in your source (in your case Class a and b). You should call NotifyPropertyChanged every time the proeprty value changes.

Then you can bind to UI controls that support INOtifyProperyChanged... that's it.

Mark response as answered.